# Excel chart : convert Y-axis values into Y-axis categories

Tags: excel

I have some data of students grades in a French scale (double values ranging from 0 to 20).
At the moment, on a scatter chart (with lines connecting dots) which permits having dates as X-axis, I have grades as doubles on my Y-axis, and a series of end of term dates as X-axis.

With the following interval mapping :

```
A = [16;20]
B = [12;16[
C = [8;12[
D = [4;8[
E = [0;4[
```

I would like to have as Y-axis these letters for grades... How can I set this up in Excel/VBA ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your situation - but I think the easiest way(from what I have seen looking on the web - this question has been asked before with no reasonable solution) is probably to just make your graph and then position text boxes containing "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" at the appropriate points along the y axis. - Kind of dumb I know - a fake axis - but it will get the job done.

Otherwise there might be a more specialized graphing program you could use.